# PMTA out of connections slot error

Tags: smtp

We have a PMTA server installed for email marketing and we are using interspire to connect to this server for sending client newsletters.

Some times, when there are too many mails going out at same time, we see this error

Unable to handle incoming SMTP connection to 127.0.0.1:2525: out of connection slots

Appearently, it does not allow more than 30 incomming connections at a time.

I was wondering if there is a setting inside PMTA config that will allow us to increase this connection limit or even make it unlimited?

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the below configuration line.

total-max-smtp-in 1000

You can also use

max-smtp-in 10

reserved-smtp-in 5

if you do use Source directive. For example,

```
<source-group localSources></source-group>
```