# Error 421 out of connection slots

Tags: smtp

whenever in my server smtp connection_in is reach to 100, i am facing this error 421(my server Name)out of connection slots. please help me to overcome this error. thank you.

Comment: Which smtp/MTA server software do you use?

Comment: hi Andrzej ...i am using powerMTA along with interspire

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PMTA out of connections slot error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16186600/pmta-out-of-connections-slot-error)